# How add custom js and css to registration page in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, css

I created a module for Magento 2, with two files to add to the user registration page:

> app/code/MyModulespace/ModuleName/view/frontend/web/css
>   /mycss.css
>
> app/code/MyModulespace/ModuleName/view/frontend/web/js/
>   myjs.js

How can I add these two files to the user registration page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create **customer_account_create.xml** at

*app/code/MyModulespace/ModuleName/view/frontend/layout/customer_account_create.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <script src="MyModulespace_ModuleName::js/myjs.js"/>
        <css src="MyModulespace_ModuleName::css/mycss.css" />
    </head>
</page>
```

Also, keep **Magento_Customer** in a sequence of your module

*app/code/MyModulespace/ModuleName/etc/module.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="MyModulespace_ModuleName" setup_version="1.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Customer"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

> **Add custom js via `requirejs-config.js`**

*app/code/MyModulespace/ModuleName/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js*

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            myjs:'MyModulespace_ModuleName/myjs'
        }
    }
};
```

*app/code/MyModulespace/ModuleName/web/js/myjs.js*

```
define('jquery', function($) {

    //Your custom js code here

    }(jQuery)
);
```

Then you can use custom js in registration template

```
<script>
// <![CDATA[
    require(['jquery','myjs'], function ($, myjs) {
        //Your code
    });
// ]]>
</script>
```

Comment: Custom js shouldn't be added this way, it needs to be added via requirejs-config.js https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/javascript-dev-guide/javascript/custom_js.html correct me if am wrong

Comment: @PrathapGunasekaran you can also add custom Js directly with a layout. But as per the question, he needs custom js only in the registration page. So for that, we also need to override registration template and then include require js.

Comment: Ok thank you, usually it happens when you add custom js without defining dependencies then if started showing function not defined. Anyway thanks for the information.