# Magento 2 add Custom CSS and JS file in admin panel

Tags: magento2, admin, javascript, css

How can add CSS and JS File in admin panel of specific page.too many pages in admin panel e.g product,sales->order ,order view ,invoice,ship etc . . .

I want to load 1 CSS or JS file in New Invoice page.

Or other solution will be work for me if add CSS or JS code in .phtml file?

how can add this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 Create a module for example `Vendor/Module`

2 Create a new file `view/adminhtml/layout/default.xml in the module`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="admin-1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
   <head>
     <css src="Vendor_Module::css/test.css"/>
     <script src="Vendor_Module::js/test.js"/>
   </head>
</page>
```

3) Add .css file and add js file  in web folder as below path:

```
view/adminhtml/web/css/test.css

view/adminhtml/web/js/test.js
```

Run below commands and check.

**php bin/magento cache:clean**

**php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy**

Comment: Rakesh Donga ! it include both files. But jquery code is not run.

`require([ 'jquery', 'jquery/ui'], function($){
    $(document).ready(function($) {
        console.log('asdf');
    });
});`

error in console is `TypeError: require is not a function`
how can write code for jquery ?

Comment: @HaFizUmer  check here : https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/266479/68695